# Creating a details page in Backbone.js for one element in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm stuck with something in Backbone.
Here's an example of an item in my collection:

```
var gifs = new GifCollection([
{image: "images/gifs/wolf.gif", 
url_title: "Wolf",
ratings: [0,0], 
rating: 3, comments: "Awesome picture.", 
title:"Wolf", category:"Animals"},
]);
```

Now in my normal/home view, I list every item through a FOR loop
Here it is:

```
            var Fill_me_with_gifs = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#fill_me_with_gifs",
            render: function () {
                var template = $("#user-view-template").html();
                var gifs_html = '';
                var gifs = this.collection.models;

                for (var gif in gifs)
                {
                    gifs_html += '<tr>';
                    gifs_html += '<td>' + "<h4>" + gifs[gif].get("title") + "</h4>" + '</td>';
                    gifs_html += '</tr>';
                    gifs_html += '<tr>';
                    gifs_html += '<td>' + "<img src=\"" + gifs[gif].get("image") + "\"" + " width=\"500\"" + ">"+ '</td>';
                    gifs_html += '</tr>';
                    gifs_html += '<tr>';
                    gifs_html += '<td>' + "<a href=\"#detail/" + gifs[gif].get("url_title") + "\"> View comments, rate and more</a>" + "</td>";
                    gifs_html += '</tr>';
                }
                this.$el.html( _.template( template, { gifs: gifs_html }));

            },

        });
```

Now I also want a details view, I already have every image with a unique link (see above) given with the url_title
For example when I click on the link below the first gif, I get redirected to #detail/Wolf
Now instead of going through a for loop, I ONLY need that one gif in my view.

I need to do this with the url_title obviously, but how exactly I don't know..

So for now I only have this as detail view:

```
        var Fill_me_with_one_gif = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#fill_me_with_gifs", 
        render: function (url_title) {
            var template = $("#user-view-template").html();     
            var gifs_html = '';
            var gifs = this.collection.models;
                //NO FOR LOOP BUT ONLY SINGLE ELEMENT FROM COLLECTION
                //I don't know what to put here :|

            },
            });
```

Here's my route for the detail page

```
            router.on("route:detail", function (url_title) {
            $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
            $("#nav-detail").addClass("active");
            console.log("Show Detail Page for " + url_title);

            var fill_me_with_one_gif = new Fill_me_with_one_gif({ collection: gifs });
            fill_me_with_one_gif.render();
```

And here's my router:

```
            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "" : "home",
            "categories" : "categories",
            "popular" : "popular",
            "detail" : "detail",
            "detail/:url_title" : "detail" //this is the one I'm having trouble with
        }
        });
```

I will be extremely thankful in help with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Backbone Collection.where()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) to select items that match a pattern. Try:

```
var matchingModels = gifs.where({
    "url_title" : url_title
});
if(matchingModels.length>0){
    //Select the first matching model
    selectedModel = matchingModels[0]
}
```

This will return an array of all matching models.  You can check for a length, then pull [0] if you're only interested in the first item.  You will have to pass url_title along with the collection to the new Fill_me_with_one_gif, or identify the model beforehand and send that (I'd likely choose the second).  To do that, your route on the detail page will look like:

```
router.on("route:detail", function (url_title) {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $("#nav-detail").addClass("active");

        var matchingModels = gifs.where({
            "url_title" : url_title
        });
        if(matchingModels.length && matchingModels.length>0){
            var fill_me_with_one_gif = new Fill_me_with_one_gif({ model: matchingModels[0] });
            fill_me_with_one_gif.render();
        } else {
            //No Matching URL TITLE?  so Dont render the details
        }
```

You can then work with only the model you need in your Fill_me_with_one_gif

Alternatively, if you've defined a model for GifCollectiion, you can use the [Backbone idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) to tell Backbone how to uniquely identify the item ala:

```
var GifCollectionItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : "url_title"
});
```

You can then select the item from the collection with {COLLECTION}.get("wolf");

EDIT  : Sorry that was convuluted.  This is the simplest answer:

```
var Fill_me_with_one_gif = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#fill_me_with_gifs", 
    render: function (url_title) {
        var template = $("#user-view-template").html();     
        var gifs_html = '';
        var matchingModels = gifs.where({
            "url_title" : url_title
        });
        if(matchingModels.length>0){
            //Select the first matching model
            selectedModel = matchingModels[0]
        }

        //THIS IS WHERE YOU DRAW THE SELECTED DETAILS
        //Use selectedModel to access your info
        //EX:  selectedModel.get("name")


    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How exactly would I add all this in my code?
Sorry if this is too much to ask, I'm just a real newbie at backbone and js :/ If you do feel generous I'll be forever grateful. 
Here's my entire current code: http://pastebin.com/hJwmijmZ

Comment: Edited my code to show the easiet answer on the bottom.  Don't forget to include the url_title when calling render() in your "route for the detail page"!

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately it doesn't work, although I don't understand why.. Was hyped for a second when you replied back with another answer, but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm so sorry to keep bothering you, if you could take a look and see what's wrong I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: No problem...I'll have some time later this weekend to take a look.  Sorry I cant help sooner

Comment: Took a quick look.  On line 272, you're rendering the single gif view, but you're not passing url_title.  Line 272 should read:
    fill_me_with_one_gif.render(url_title);

Hopefully that's all you need.  What are you seeing in your javascript console?

Comment: It's not showing anything, it's not even reloading the page when I click a detail link. When I shift reload after clicking I get an empty page. In the console it does say "Show Detail Page for Wolf" though.

Comment: And thank you so much for helping me so far, I'll keep checking here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40415/discussion-between-matthias-verhoeven-and-user1026361)